# Vagrant shell provisioning is not working

Tags: vagrant

I have been trying to use vagrant to set up an Ubuntu virtual machine on Windows for Rails development.

What I did was first create a "plain" vm and SSHed into it and then ran all the commands that I need such as sudo apt-get install x to make sure that they worked (which they did), before putting them into a shell script.

When I try run vagrant up using the shell script that I made it falls over with an extremely long error message with things such as stdin: is not a tty and other equally cryptic error messages.

My vagrant file looks like this:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "precise32"
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "Vagrant.sh" 
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 3003, guest: 3000,  auto_correct: true

end
```

My shell script is here (because it is a little long and GitHub provide syntax highlighting):
https://gist.github.com/leebrooks0/5477591

and the console output is here:
https://gist.github.com/leebrooks0/5477627

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

After more trying I have realised that not even the demo script from the vagrant docs (http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/provisioning.html) works, which is quite strange because that script definitely worked yesterday when I started this work and tried it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
/tmp/vagrant-shell: line 5: $'\r': command not found
```

line 5

```
echo 'Updating system packages...'
```

looks like possible issue with windows "carriage return / line feed" `\r\n` vs unix "new line" `\n`

consider also using chef-solo option in vagrant file, takes a bit to get used to chef, but probably worth it - http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/chef_solo.html

Comment: I also did notice that but I dismissed it (perhaps foolishly) because the sample shell script from the docs did work yesterday. I have been looking into puppet and chef, but I thought one new trick at a time :) Why do you recommend chef over puppet by the way?

Comment: I used this tip to convert my line endings into unix line endings.http://superuser.com/questions/479756/eol-in-notepad-and-notepad.

Comment: i don't think you can go wrong learning either one, chef seemed easier to pick up for me, chef-solo and knife make it easy without needing a provision server - some good blog posts out there doing comparisons: https://www.google.com/search?q=chef+or+puppet